# Matlab circuit simulation

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape, simpowersystems

I am new to **MATLAB** and i want so simulate basic circuit, but i can't connect elements together. All i get is some red dotted line and a warning:

```
Unconnected output line found on 'D1/DC Voltage Source' (output port: 1)
```

How can i connect those elements together? Here is an image of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

I know it's a rookie question, but i didn't find an answer using Google.

Comment: There are much better tools for circuit simulation than MATLAB, btw.  Also, since you are not using the programming features of MATLAB, this question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matlab version: R2012a
I find the **Series RLC Branch** block used under **Simscape -> SimPowerSystems -> Elements**,
and the **DC Voltage Source** block used under **Simscape -> Foundation Library -> Electrical Sources**. The 2 nodes are both white **rectangles.**
And there is another **DC Voltage Source** block under **Simscape -> SimPowerSystems -> Electrical Sources**. The 2 nodes are both white **squares**.
There are some difference in the appearence of this two sources such as the shape of node. Maybe the function is different too.
After i connect these blocks, the red dotted line indeed disappear.

I think the reason is that ***electrical*** and ***powersystem*** are very different things.
When you simulate basic circut, you should use blocks under the same branch to avoid electrical conflict.

[image: My simulation]